# trying to use an object to populate a list <> and grab attributes for calculations

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, object

So my assignment was to create a Windows form with simple buttons to handle click events for calculating the order total and displaying it using a separate class, and a click event for displaying the total order details for the day (hinted to use a private `arraylist` or a `list<>`).

The program is a simple point of sale environment for a pizza shop. I've got three text boxes for user input

```
(int numberOfCokes, int numberOfPizzas, double cashGiven).
```

I have a 'Calculate Total' button which instantiates an object of the `PizzaOrder` class (i called it `order`) and uses methods to calculate it and throw all of the output into a message box back on the gui side. This has been successful.

My issue now is that I have a `DisplaySummary` class which is supposed to total up the total number of orders for the day, total # AND dollar amount of pizzas sold, and the total # AND dollar amount of cokes sold.

I'm trying to use `List <PizzaOrder> OrderList = new List<PizzaOrder>()` as my way of storing order objects but I don't know how to take and count the attributes of each object. I am supposed to use a minimum of three methods within this class and pass the output to a multiline textbox for when the Display Summary button is clicked.

I would really appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which are the methods and fields you have in your PizzaOrder class, but assuming you have in that one the cost of the pizzas and the cost of the cokes, you could add a static field for the number of orders which is incremented every time you instantiate a new object of this class, a static field for the total cost of pizzas, a static field for the cost of cokes.

something like:

```
class PizzaOrder(){
    private static int totalOrders=0;
    private static double totalPizza=0;
    private static double totalCokes=0;
    public PizzaOrder(){
    totalOrders++;
    //Other stuffs
    }
    public static int GetTotalOrders(){
    return totalOrders;
    }
    public void AddPizza(double costOfPizza){
    totalPizza+=costOfPizza;
    }
    public static double GetTotalPizza(){
    return totalPizza;
    }
    //Something similar for cokes

}
```

Of course you could've used setters & getters for the single properties, but since it seems you're just getting started I thought it would've been easier for you this way.

Comment: OP said they are expected to use a `List<T>`, this just circumvents the problem with a cheap hack (keep totals as static fields in the class rather than putting instances in a container and doing operations on it).

Comment: Didn't read (in the unedited version) that it was a requirement.
Considering that he's just starting I thought of hinting him to a more simple solution with constructs he was sure to have studied.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll just give you a couple of suggestions and let you complete the details.

```
     List<PizzaOrder> orders = new List<PizzaOrder>(); // in summary class 

     // in onclick handler for Calc total
     orders.Add(newInstance);

     // in the display part of summary class
     int totalCokes = orders.Aggregate((c, n) => c.numberOfCokes + n.numberOfCokes);
     int cokeRevenue = totalCokes * PriceOfACoke;
      //ect
```

So basically, I would recommend making your list of type `PizzaOrder`. Each time you get a new order you add it to the list. When the user wants to see the summary, iterate over the list or use LINQ queries like my aggregate query above to get the totals and display them to the user. A simple `foreach` would be easier than what I have. In the class you could have those properties for say totalcokes, add the value for each object in the body of the loop then you derive the total dollars (i called it `cokeRevenue`) outside of the loop. Have one method to calculate the totals, have another that works with your display layer (sets values in text boxes or whatever).